# How Do I Disable Multi-threaded debugging Feather for vscode C/C++

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

My program has hundreds of threads causing C/C++ initialization to be very slow. Check whether a configuration item disables the C/C++ multi-thread debugging feature.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u8lJ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.